# Как построить алгоритм удаления повторяющихся значений в связном списке?Java

Tags: java

Я написал код для выделения памяти заполнения и тому подобное, но не понимаю как удалить повторяющиеся элементы

```
public class List {

     private Node head; 
     public List() 
     { 
     head=null; 
     } 
     public void add(int x) 
     { 
     head = new Node(x, head); 
     } 
     private static class Node 
     { 
     private int value; 
     private Node next; 
     private Node(int v, Node n) 
     { 
     value=v; 
     next=n; 
     } 
     } 

     public void print() 
     { 
     Node h=head; 
     while (h!=null) 
     { 
     System.out.print(h.value+" "); 
     h=h.next; 
     } 
     System.out.println(); 
     } 

    } 
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
         List l=new List(); 
         for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++ )
         { 
        l.add(i%6); 
         } 
         l.print();  


        } 
}
```

Comment: а как насчет использования сета вместо листа либо дистинкт в стримах?

Comment: Такое задание( Препод так сказал делать, еле с этим разобрался

Comment: так делайте, я не вижу противоречий....

Comment: Посмотрите как работает `LinkedHashSet`. Задание, которое вы описали - его прямая задача.